# How to calculate/count the number of extreme precipitation events (above a "threshold") from daily rainfall data in each month per year basis

Tags: r, count, threshold

I am working on daily rainfall data and trying to evaluate the extreme events from the time series data above a certain threshold value in each month per year i.e. the number of times the rainfall exceeded a certain threshold in each month per year.

The rainfall timeseries data is from St Lucia and has two columns:

1. "YEARMODA" - defining the time (format- YYYYMMDD)
2. "PREP" - rainfall in mm (numeric)

   StLucia <- read_excel("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/StLuciaProject.xlsx")

The dataframe which I'm working i.e "Precip1" on has two columns namely:

1. Time (format YYYY-MM-DD)
2. Precipitation (numeric value)

The code is provided below:

```
library("imputeTS")
StLucia$YEARMODA <- as.Date(as.character(StLucia$YEARMODA), format = "%Y%m%d")

data1 <- na_ma(StLucia$PREP, k=4, weighting = "exponential")

Precip1 <- data.frame(Time= StLucia$YEARMODA, Precipitation= data1, check.rows = TRUE)
```

I found out the threshold value based on the 95th percentile and 99th percentile using function `quantile()`.

I now want to count the number of "extreme events" of rainfall above this threshold in each month on per year basis.

Please help me out on this. I would be highly obliged by your help. Thank You!

Comment: It would be helpful i you could provide a subset of your data (e.g. using `dput`) to make this problem reproducible -- much easier for people to help when they can run it on their own machines. Thanks :)

Comment: @mysteRious, I'm not able to send the data from there. Can you please elaborate the process to me for doing that. Thanks!

Comment: See this question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to a `tidyverse` method, here is an example with the `economics` dataset that is built into `ggplot2`. We can use `ntile` to assign a percentile group to each observation. Then we `group_by` the year, and get a count of the values that are in the desired percentiles. Because this is monthly data the counts are pretty low, but it's easily translated to daily data.

```r
library(tidyverse)
thresholds <- economics %>%
  mutate(
    pctile = ntile(unemploy, 100),
    year = year(date)
    ) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(
    q95 = sum(pctile >= 95L),
    q99 = sum(pctile >= 99L)
    )
arrange(thresholds, desc(q95))
#> # A tibble: 49 x 3
#>     year   q95   q99
#>    <dbl> <int> <int>
#>  1  2010    12     6
#>  2  2011    12     0
#>  3  2009    10     5
#>  4  1967     0     0
#>  5  1968     0     0
#>  6  1969     0     0
#>  7  1970     0     0
#>  8  1971     0     0
#>  9  1972     0     0
#> 10  1973     0     0
#> # ... with 39 more rows
```

Created on 2018-06-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: can you explain me this code ' pctile = ntile(unemploy, 100)' which you have mentioned above. Thanks

Comment: Also, is it possible to set the threshold in the code **manually** without using the percentiles?

Comment: `ntile` takes arguments `x`, a vector, and `n`, a number of buckets. It returns a vector of same length as `x` with values corresponding to the bucket that the values of `x` fit in. So with `n = 100`, the smallest 1% of values get `pctile = 1`, the 95th % gets `pctile = 95`. So we just count the number above the 95th percentile.

Comment: Yes you can set a manual threshold, just use `sum(unemploy > threshold)` inside summarise

Comment: Also mam, is it possible to know the number of peaks above the defined threshold at Six Months intervals i.e. the number of peaks that are above the threshold in the first six months are independent from the peaks present in next six months of a year. I want to do this since I want to characterise the peaks above the threshold in dry and wet season respectively in a year.